# OSX: After upgrading to 10.11.2, terminal always start in Node

Tags: node.js, macos, bash, terminal

Anytime I open up Terminal it starts with Node. I have no idea why this happens. I haven't seen this anywhere else.

In preferences - Shell opens with: /bin/bash

Anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Hmmm...  Check Preferences -> Profiles -> General and make sure "Login Shell" is selected under "Command". Are you running any Node scripts from .bashrc or .bash_profile?

Comment: I just checked in .bash_profile and this was there:

/usr/local/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/npm

I just removed these two lines and now node throws and error and exits out.

Comment: Last login: Sat Apr  9 14:44:15 on ttys004
node ◂ -bash
Nicholass-iMac:~ nick$ node ◂ -bash
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/nick/◂'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:968:3

Comment: This is what happens everytime I start terminal